# How to implement third party caches into custom class or library

Tags: php

I'm currently developing a small class which would heavily benefit from a caching solution, since it'l make HTTP request to third party APIs.

I don't really want to force the user into some specific pre-implemented caching solution. I also want to keep the usage really simple.

Instead I'd prefer to let the user of the class decide which caching mechanism he or she would use.

What would be in this case a best practice implementation?

I thought a simple getter/setter method would be appropriate:

```
$class->retrieveFromCache(function() {
    return UserDefinedCache::get('user_defined_key');
});

$class->writeToCache(function($value) {
    UserDefinedCache::set('user_defined_key', $value);
});
```

This empowers the user to use whatever cache he or she wants. Keeping the implementation and usage dead simple.

Besides the class also has to store and retrieve a value from a cookie. I'd implement the accessors for it in a similar way. So the user is free to use the cookie mechanism which fits best his or her environment or framework.

```
$class->getCookieValue(function() {
    return $_COOKIE['custom_name'];
});

$class->setCookieValue(function($value) {
    setcookie('custom_name', $value);
});
```

Would this be a good implementation? Are there some disadvantages which I overlooked? Or are there better solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[I would follow the PSR-6 proposal](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted%2FPSR-6-cache.md).

If you want to feature multiple adapters there are probably several ways to archive this. Have a factory like this

```
$cacheInstance = CacheFactory::get('MyFancyCacheAdapter', ['options' => 'here']);
```

That returns a configured instance  of the given adapter. An adapter should implement the PSR-6 CacheItemPoolInterface.

However you implement it the primary thing to keep in mind is that all cache engines or adapters should implement the same interface so they're easy to switch and work with.

On the other side, I wouldn't try to re-invent the wheel. There are already well done cache libs, [like this one for example](https://github.com/cakephp/cache). If you don't like it, I think you can find many others as well.

> Besides the class also has to store and retrieve a value from a cookie. I'd implement the accessors for it in a similar way. So the user is free to use the cookie mechanism which fits best his or her environment or framework.

A cookie is no cache. Technically you could implement a cache engine and store the data in a cookie but I think this is very misleading, technically incorrect and is not following the principle of separation of concerns.

Comment: Maybe I asked not clearly enough. I'd like to keep it simple. Eg. a user of my library could also use his mysql database as cache. I don't really see a benefit in forcing him or her to adapt a caching interface. I also don't want to blow my library with third party cache dependencies.

Concering the cookies: These should not be used as a cache. The library needs to write some data to a end user's cookie. I don't really want to mess up the projects, in which the library will be used, by adding cookie headers. This behaviour should be controlled by the user of the library.

Comment: It makes absolutely no sense to *not* implement an interface and to enforce it if you want to allow different cache backends. If you want it simple but not follow any common patterns then simply create a class for each cache and just implement a getter and setter. Otherwise I don't get your problem.